# Access npm package globally

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed the node-github package on my Ubuntu machine using `sudo npm install -g github`, however if I would try to access it in the node REPL it would throw a `Cannot find module 'github'` error. If I run the REPL from `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` though, it works fine.

How can this package be accessed universally?

Comment: Is the global install location in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis output of `$PATH` is here :
 http://pastebin.com/zvaUS3wh It does contain /usr/local/lib/node_modules